# Why operator<< does not implicitly converting my custome class object to string

Tags: c++, class, templates, type-conversion, operator-overloading

I have a class implemented a public `string` conversion memeber function. When coupled with `operator<<(iostream &, xxx)` , what I expect is that my class would be automatically(implicitly) converted to `string` thus suits for the parameter type.

However, that's not true. Why, I don't wanna to write a `operation<<` function.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    operator string() { return "asd"; }
};

int main() {
    cout << A() << endl;  // error
    cout << string(A()) << endl; // ok
}
```

Comment: `operator<<` taking an `std::string` (or, to be precise, `std::basic_string`) is a template. Implicit conversions are not considered during template parameter deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`operator<<` for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is a template, and implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which fails.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

As you've showed, you can convert `A` to `std::string` explicitly, or write an `operator<<` for `A`.